# How do I add link to Edit and Delete in a column in a view table item list?

Tags: views, forms, database

I've trying to add a link to Edit and Delete column to perform desirable actions. I need help in implementing it. I've tried several suggested methods on the internet, but none did the job for me. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

**Here is my Controller.php**

```
public function getAdList(){
            $limit = 3;
            $query = \Drupal::database();
            $result = $query->select('ad_form_submissions','u')
                    ->fields('u',['id','name','crop_category','crop_type','quantity','price'])
                    ->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')->limit($limit)
                    ->execute()->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            $data = [];
            $count = 1;

            $params = \Drupal::request()->query->all();

            if(empty($params) || $params['page'] == 0){
                $count=1;
            }else if($params['page'] == 1){
                $count = $params['page'] + $limit;
            }else{
                $count = $params['page'] * limit;
                $count++;
            }

            foreach($result as $row){
                $data[] = [
                    'S_no'=> $count.".",
                    'ID'=> $row->id,
                    'Name'=> $row->name,
                    'Crop Category'=> $row->crop_category,
                    'Crop Type'=> $row->crop_type,
                    'Quantity'=> $row->quantity,
                    'Price'=> $row->price,
                    'Edit' => 'Edit',
                    'Delete'=>'Delete'
                ];
                $count++;
            }

            $header = array('S_no','ID','Name','Crop Category','Crop Type','Quantity','Price','Edit','Delete');

            $build['table'] = [
                '#type'=>'table',
                '#header'=>$header,
                '#rows'=>$data,
                '#empty' => t('No users found'),
            ];

            $build['parger'] = [
                '#type'=>'pager'
            ];

            return [
                $build,
                '#title'=> 'Submit Ad List'
            ];
        
        }
```

Clarification: I want to perform the Edit and Delete Task on the selected row.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for Entity Operations. Soul you'd have to load the enity by ID, and then use the getoperations methods. Looking at your code though, I would suggest you use EntityTypeManager to instead load your entities with a [EntityListController](https://www.drupal.org/node/1799642) or something equivalent, it's all baked into core.